# issue with imports relative paths in vscode

Tags: import, path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ymhK.png)
When trying to import files from different files and starting with "./' I get the icons without extensions and beneath the normal icons. Sometimes I only get the relative path with no correct icons. Is this a normal behaviour? If I do not type "import" I just get the normal icons like so [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPhSY.png)> is there a way to fix it? I disabled path intellisense and npm intellisense and i do not see any other relevant settings in settings.json that could lead to this. So I am wondering wether is normal or not

Tried to disable all extensions and path intellisense